# association doesn't get deleted with dependent: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, destroy

I have a join model `item_photos` for `item` and `photo` models

```
class ItemPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :photo
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_photos
    has_many :photos, through: :item_photos, dependent: :destroy
end


class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_photos, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :items, through: :item_photos, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When deleting a Photo, I want to delete the item if its the last one (sort of reference counting), or at least, be able to run some code right before

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with an Association callback, like `after_remove`.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_photos, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :item_photos, dependent: :destroy, after_remove: :do_stuff

  private

  def do_stuff
    # ...
  end
end
```

Documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html (no direct link, but search for Association callbacks)